# What is the use of spring.net?

Tags: c#, wcf, silverlight, spring.net

We are developing an application using Silverlight and WCF Services. Is using Spring.Net is beneficial for us?

Comment: What is the use of Quartz with Spring.net?

Comment: In my experience, I've never seen dependency injection used properly.  There were always just a few places where it made sense to use and it ends up getting used in all classes, creating a convoluted, configuration mountain of a mess!  Please don't use something just because it is the latest buzz word in the tech community.  Remember, when you introduce a new pattern into your project, then someone needs to manage that pattern and make sure the code stays clean.  So the less extras you add the better.  ONLY add what is needed!  PLEASE!!!!!

Answer (score 7):

>> "Is using Spring.Net is beneficial for us?"

I think the spirit of your question is really geared more towards questioning the benefit of using an IoC/DI framework versus manually managing dependencies as needed. My response will focus more on the why and why not of IoC/DI and not so much on which specific framework to use.

As Martin Fowler mentioned at a recent conference, DI allows you to separate configuration from usage. For me, thinking about DI in the light of configuration and usage as separate concerns is a great way to start asking the right questions. Is there a need for your application to have multiple configurations for your dependencies? Does your app need the ability to modify behavior by configuration? Keep in mind, this means that dependencies are resolved at runtime and typically require an XML configuration file which is nice because changes can be made without requiring a recompile of the assembly. Personally, I'm not a fan of XML-based configuration of dependencies as they end up being consumed as "magic strings". So there's the danger of introducing runtime errors if you end up misspelling a class name, etc. But if you need the ability to configure on-the-fly, this is probably the best solution today.

On the other hand, there are DI frameworks like Ninject and StructureMap that allow fluent in-code dependency definitions. You lose the ability to change definitions on-the-fly, but you get the added benefit of compile time validations, which I prefer. If all you want from a DI framework is to resolve dependencies then you could eliminate XML-based frameworks from the equation.

From a Silverlight perspective, DI can be used in various ways. The most obvious is to define the relationship of Views to ViewModels. Going deeper, however, you can define validation, and RIA context dependencies, etc. Having all of the dependencies defined in a configuration class keeps the code free from needing to know how to get/create instances and instead focus on usage. Don't forget that the container can manage the lifetime of each object instance based on your config. So if you need to share an instance of a type (e.g. Singleton, ManagedThread, etc.), this is supported by declaring the lifetime scope of each type registered with the container.

I just realized at this point I'm ranting and I apologize. Hope this helps!

Comment: if we are going to do it run time... then what's the point? i mean we can just do that without even having a framework, and without injecting them, just simply pass the parameter to objects...??? and also there are lot of things spring claim that is capable of... what about them?

Answer (score 4):

Personally i'd recommend using either Castle or Unity as i've had great success with both and found them both, while different, excellent IOC frameworks.

Besides the IOC component they also provide other nifty tools (AOP in Castle, Interface interception in Unity, for example) which you will no doubt find a use for in the future, and having an IOC framework in place from the start is ALWAYS a hell of a lot easier than trying to retrofit it.

It's incredibly easy to setup and configure, although personally i'm not a huge fan of the XML config way of doing things as some of those config files can turn into a total nightmare. A lot of people will tell you that it's only worth doing if you intend to swap components in and out, but why not just do that anyway IN CASE you decide you need to do that later. it's better to have it and not use it, than not have it and need it. If you're worried about perf hit i've seen on many blog posts around the web people comparing the various IOC frameworks for their speed and unless you're creating brain surgery robots or the US Missile defence platform it won't be an issue.

Answer (score 3):

A DI Framework might be of use if you want to change big chunks of your application without having to rewrite your constructors. For example, you might want to use a comet streaming service that you will expose through an interface, and later decide that you'd rather use a dedicated messenging system such as MQ or RendezVous. You will then write an adapter to Mq that respects the common facade and just change the spring config to use the Mq implementation rather than the Comet one.

But for the love of *tony the pony*, don't use Spring.Net to create your MVVM/MVP/MVC bindings for each and every view or you'll enter a world of pain.

DI is a great tool when used with parcimony, please don't end-up with 243 spring configuration files, for your devs' sanity.

Answer (score 2):

Using an IOC container such as Spring.Net is beneficial as it will enable you to unit test parts of your UI by swapping in mocked or special test implementations of the applications interfaces.  In the long run, this should make your application more maintainable for future developers.

Comment: Use the MOQ library for unit tests.  Introducing a framework and using it everywhere  just for unit tests is not a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

I think if you do more in the code rather than using the markup to do bindings etc. and have a BAL/DAL DI can help there because it can inject the correct business component reference (as one example).  DI has many other practical advantages, but then you have to do more in code and less in markup.